# How to set not null column via Schema.Builder in Flink?

Tags: apache-flink, flink-table-api

When I was create table via Table API, my code looks like this:

```java
Schema.Builder schemaBuilder = Schema.newBuilder();
schemaBuilder.column("id", DataTypes.BIGINT())
        .column("value", DataTypes.STRING())
        .primaryKey("id");
```

then I get an exception like this:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.flink.table.api.ValidationException: Invalid primary key 'PK_id'. Column 'id' is nullable.
```

Yes, I know primary key can not be null, but how to set it? I have no idea right now.

Thank you guys.

I have to find document on Flink official website, but no result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
Schema.Builder schemaBuilder = Schema.newBuilder();
schemaBuilder.column("id", DataTypes.BIGINT().notNull())
        .column("value", DataTypes.STRING())
        .primaryKey("id");
```